# Syntax error on Paste Special from ThisWorkbook to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

First line of code works fine, second errors out with a syntax error. I want it to do the same thing as first line except paste values only.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Range("A4"), Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Range("G4"), Range("G4").End(xlDown)).Copy .Sheets(1).Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Full code for the sub

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Workbooks.Add
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Range("A4"), Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Range("G4"), Range("G4").End(xlDown)).Copy .Sheets(1).Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs "C:\Users\my username\Desktop\Macro Demo\output.xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a `paste:=` Edit: or you [need](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) `(`?

Comment: Make the paste special two lines not one.

Comment: Does it matter that the paste is happening in a new workbook?  Not sure what you mean by make it 2 lines, or where to put paste:= in my existing code.  I am complete noob sorry :(

Comment: `paste is happening in a new workbook` yea, that matters. I hope you have a `with` that qualifies the desired book that you left out. Also, see my link to see where to put `paste:=` Edit: if you just want values, set the ranges to each other.

Comment: I added the full code snippet

Comment: @findwindow where would I insert the paste:= ?

Comment: Er, as I said, check the link. But that's not your only problem. @jeeped caught something crucial below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("A4")` and `Range("A4").End(xlDown)` may not belong to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` and you cannot define a range using cells from another worksheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim nwb As Workbook

    Set nwb = Workbooks.Add

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range(.Range("A4"), .Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=nwb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        With .Range(.Range("G4"), .Range("G4").End(xlDown))
            nwb.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Resize(.Rows.Count, 1) = .Value
        End With
    End With

    With nwb
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs "C:\Users\my username\Desktop\Macro Demo\output.xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: yeah the first line of code works fine if I remove the paste special line....not sure what you mean with this one

Comment: Jeeped is saying, you need to qualify _all_ ranges.

Comment: @JamesPage - See above for a more complete rewrite from the additional code you updated with.

Comment: Was just trying it and had an extra END IF in there haha, i see you updated.  Trying momentarily

Comment: @jeeped Awesome man!!!!!!!  not sure I understand fully what you've done or why there is a resize function in there but YAY!   Only 1 hiccup, it automatically added formatting to column B in new wb.  It somehow kept the formatting from original copy even though we specified values only?  It formats column B as currency

Comment: Always explicitly supply a parent to cells, ranes and the cells/ranges that define them. I've use a with end with and prefaced everything with a `.`. The resize gis necessary because direct values transfer requires the destination be the same size as the source. The additional with/end with allows us to use `.Rows.Count` which is the rows within the source. If you want raw values then use `.Value2`, the `.Value` can carry regional information in dates and currency values.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description of the code.  Value2 did the trick....Thank you so much!